# Web Filter for Weblogic to catch POST requests

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm in real an embedded programmer and really very new to weblogic programming so please forgive me for possible epic fail question. I tried to check out web but couldn't find a good start point for the issue.
I have a preparatory weblogic application lies on Weblogic 10.3.2. In application there is a page which waits some fields to input and POST it with address ...../actions/service/device/wizard/jump-properties?device_id=1818&acsrf_req_idt=8987a72ff90ba240b78b89e

what i want to do is, capture this posted field somehow and also take the device_id from the header and do some custom actions as a result of this post. Are there a way to me to install  some filter to web.xml of application and catch all bypassing requests and look for a POST request for page .../actions/service/device/wizard/jump-properties. Then I may do some custom things maybe?

Many thanks for the help in advance,

goktan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html
or http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Servlet_Filters/  and/or
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-2001/jw-0622-filters.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Romain, it exactly seems what I need.